# how to set image according my condition in custom listview

Tags: android

I just want to add images to different item according to my condition.
e.g.if status is equal to open then set open.png img status is equal to wip then wip.png status is equal to closed then closed.png and after setting images i want to open the activity according to ticket no and show all the detail of ticket on item click. so what should i write to set image and code to write on item method.i am new  in android, here is my code

```
class viewticket extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

         @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pdialog = new ProgressDialog(UserLogedIn.this);
            pdialog.setMessage("Loading....");
            pdialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pdialog.setCancelable(false);
            pdialog.show();
         }

         @Override
         protected String doInBackground(String... params)  {
            List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", u_id));
                      // JSONObject jsonArray = jpar.makeHttpRequest(URLMyTicket, "POST", param);

             ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();


                      String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(URLMyTicket, ServiceHandler.POST, param);
             Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
             if (jsonStr != null)

             {
                 try {

                    contacts = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                     a=contacts.length();
                    Log.v(TAG, ".................." + a);

                    if(a > 0 ) {
                        id = new String[contacts.length()];
                        stats = new String[contacts.length()];
                        due_date = new String[contacts.length()];
                        prob = new String[contacts.length()];

                        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                            String aa = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                            String bb = c.getString(TAG_PROB);
                            String cc = c.getString(TAG_status);
                            String dd = c.getString(TAG_due_date);

                            Log.v(TAG, "TAG_ID" + aa);
                            Log.v(TAG, "TAGPROB" + bb);
                            Log.v(TAG, "TAGPROB" + cc);
                            Log.v(TAG, "TAGPROB" + dd);

                            id[i] = aa;
                            prob[i] = bb;
                            stats[i] = cc;
                            due_date[i] = dd;

                            Log.v(TAG, "aaaaa" + id[i]);
                            Log.v(TAG, "bbbbb" + prob[i]);
                            Log.v(TAG, "cccc" + stats[i]);
                            Log.v(TAG, "dddd" + due_date[i]);


                        }

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                  System.out.print("hiiiiiiiiiiii" );
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String  result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog

            Log.v(TAG, "length of aaaaa" + a);
            if(id!=null && id.length > 0 )
            {
                        Ticket_adapter adapter=new Ticket_adapter(UserLogedIn.this,id,prob,stats,due_date);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            else
            {
                      Toast.makeText(UserLogedIn.this, "No Ticket Present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            pdialog.hide();
            pdialog.dismiss();



             }

            }
```

so could you please write code for me to set image according to status and how to write onitemclicklistener method.

adapter class

```
public class Ticket_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
Context context;
String[] id;
String[] prob;
String[] stats;
String[] due_date;
int [] stimg;

LayoutInflater inflater;

public Ticket_adapter(UserLogedIn context, String[] id,String[] prob,String[] stats,String[] due_date,int[] stimg) {
    super(context, R.id.list_item,id);
    this.context=context;
    this.id=id;
    this.prob=prob;
   this.stats=stats;
    this.due_date=due_date;
    this.stimg=stimg;

}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);

    }
    TextView idtxt=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.uid);
    TextView probtxt=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.prob);
    TextView stustxt=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);
    TextView duetxt=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.duedate);
    ImageView immm=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image12);
    idtxt.setText(id[position]);
    probtxt.setText(prob[position]);
    stustxt.setText(stats[position]);
    duetxt.setText(due_date[position]);
    immm.setImageResource(stimg[position]);


    return convertView;

}
```

}

Comment: @George please slove my problem sir

Comment: i have edited my question.added adapter in question

Comment: you should always use a viewholder pattern when creating adapter otherwise there will be lot of issues

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Ticket_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
Context context;
String[] id;
String[] prob;
String[] stats;
String[] due_date;
int [] stimg;

LayoutInflater inflater;

public Ticket_adapter(UserLogedIn context, String[] id,String[] prob,String[] stats,String[] due_date,int[] stimg) {
    super(context, R.id.list_item,id);
    this.context=context;
    this.id=id;
    this.prob=prob;
   this.stats=stats;
    this.due_date=due_date;
    this.stimg=stimg;

}


    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView idtxt;
    public TextView probtxt;
    public TextView stustxt;
    public TextView duetxt;
        public ImageView immm;
      }

     @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;
            if (rowView == null) {
                  LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
                  rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                  // configure view holder
                  ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                  viewHolder.idtxt= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.uid);
             viewHolder.probtxt= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.prob);
             viewHolder.stustxt= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.status);
             viewHolder.duetxt= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.duedate);
                  viewHolder.immm= (ImageView) rowView
                      .findViewById(R.id.image12);
                  rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
                }

              viewHolder.idtxt.setText(id[position]);
              viewHolder.probtxt.setText(prob[position]);
              viewHolder.stustxt.setText(stats[position]);
              viewHolder.duetxt.setText(due_date[position]);
             if(stats[position].equals("open"))
                {
                 viewHolder.immm.setImageResource(R.drawable.openimage);
                }
               else if(stats[position].equals("wip"))
               {
                viewHolder.immm.setImageResource(R.drawable.wipimage);
                }
               else
                {
                   viewHolder.immm.setImageResource(R.drawable.closedimage);
                }

               return rowView;
              }
            }
```

Comment: apart from that is there any changes required

Comment: please show me write full code for my adapter class sir

Comment: i am confused to where to write that code because i am new to android

Comment: i have not debugged this please implement and debug

Comment: sir give me full code for adapter now there are need to make some changes in server side i just need to write that code first

Comment: give me code because i am confused where to start that viewholderclass

Comment: man i have already given everything for you to implement, check the answer

Comment: getlayoutinflator and viewHolder.idtxt.setText(id[position]);//only viewholder in red
        viewHolder.probtxt.setText(prob[position]);//only viewholder in red
        viewHolder.stustxt.setText(stats[position]);//only viewholder in red
        viewHolder.duetxt.setText(due_date[position]); comes in red //only viewholder in red

Comment: have you pasted the ViewHolder class

Comment: http://android-start.yolasite.com/posts.php here it has a post how to create a custom list in android

Answer (score 0):

in your `getView()` method

```
  if(stats[position].Equals("open"))
    {
     immm.setImageResource(R.drawable.open);
    }
   else if(stats[position].Equals("wip"))
   {
    immm.setImageResource(R.drawable.wip);
    }
   else
    {
       immm.setImageResource(R.drawable.closed);
    }
```